# Simple integration problem from real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, integration

If $f$ is continuous and nonnegative on the interval $[a, b]$ and $$\int_a^b f(x)dx=0$$ show that $f$ is identically equal to zero there.

This is intuitively obvious but I think we're supposed to prove it using the **monotone property**.

> **Monotone Property:** Let $f$ and $g$ be continuous on $[a, b]$. Then, if $f(x)\le g(x)\ \forall a\le x\le b$,
>   $$\int_a^bf(x)dx\le\int_a^bg(x)dx$$

Any hints would be much appreciated.

Comment: Indeed, given a continuous nonnegative function $f$ which is not identically zero, try to find a function $g$ with $g \leq f$ such that $g$ can be exactly integrated and $\int_a^b g(x) dx>0$. (You can make $g$ continuous but it might be easier to make it piecewise constant instead.) Then applying the monotone property gives the desired result through contraposition.

Answer (score 1):

You must assume $a < b$: the claim is false if $a=b$.

If it's not identically $0$, then there is some $\epsilon > 0$ and interval $(c,d) \subseteq (a,b)$ on which $f(x) > \epsilon > 0$.  Then $\int_a^b f(x)\; dx \ge (d-c)\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that there exists $x\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x)\ne 0$.

You have $f(x)>0$ because $f$ is nonnegative.

Then since $f$ is continuous, there existe $\epsilon,\eta >0$ such that $f(y)>\eta$ for all $y$ in $[x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon]$.

(if $x=a$ or $x=b$ you have to be careful, but it is basically the same idea)

Then since $f$ is positive, you have

$$\int_a^b f(x)\mathrm d x\geqslant \int_{x-\epsilon}^{x+\epsilon} f(x)\mathrm d x>2\epsilon\eta>0.$$

You have a contradiction.

Comment: Just $f(y)>0$ is technically not enough, you need $f$ strictly bounded below. (It is technically true that any positive continuous function on an interval integrates to a positive number, but the proof of that is basically the same difficulty as the proof of the desired result.)

Comment: And don't see why it would not be enough since $f$ is bounded below by $0$

Comment: It's not enough because if the only lower bound you have is $0$ then the lower sum for a partition is just bounded below by $0$. But if you have a positive lower bound, say you knew $f(x_0)>\epsilon$ and then $f(x)>\epsilon/2$ near $x_0$, then the lower sum is bounded below by a positive constant and everything works out.

Comment: @lan I see it now. I edited to correct that. Thanks for your comments !

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Suppose

$\exists c \in[a,b]\; f(c)>0$.

$f$ continuous at $x=c \implies$

$$\exists \eta>0\;:\;\forall [a,b]\cap [c-\eta,c+\eta]  $$

$$ \frac{f(c)}{2}<f(x)<3\frac{f(c)}{2}$$

$$\implies \int_a^bf(x)dx\geq \int_{c-\eta}^{c+\eta}\frac{f(c)}{2}>0$$

it is a contradiction.